# Replace all Windows-1252 characters to the respective UTF-8 ones

Tags: encoding

I looking to a way to recursively replace all imcompatible windows-1252 caracteres to the respective utf-8 ones.

I tried iconv, without success.

I also found the following command:

```
grep -rl oldstring . |xargs sed -i -e 's/oldstring/newstring/'
```

But I'll not like to exec this command by hand for every charactere.

Is there a way or software that can do that?